# How to workaround a nodejs stable bug with setInterval/setTimeout when changing system time

Tags: node.js, timer, settimeout, setinterval

In the current stable version of node.js v0.10.33 [there is a bug](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/nodejs/138dfge2rk/settimeout-and-setinterval-issue-when-wall-clock-changes) where setTimeout/setInterval does not fire anymore when setting the system time to the past.

Run this code to see what I mean:

```
var i = 0;

var handle = setInterval(function()
{
    console.log(++i);
}, 1000);
```

Then while it's running change the time of your system to the past, does not matter if on windows or linux. The interval / timeout will not fire anymore. When chaning the time to the future, node behaves perfectly fine and keeps running the interval. This bug was fixed in node v0.11.3 which I cannot use yet because it is not stable.

I tried modules like [timer-shim](https://www.npmjs.com/package/timer-shim) and [nanotimer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nanotimer) but they internally use setInterval/setTimeout aswell and thus have the same problem.

For the time being, how can I woraround this node bug for my application in the best possible way without funky monkey patching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in older versions of the 0.10 branch: https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v0.10.36/