# Node.js setTimeout not fired after system time change

Tags: javascript, node.js, timer

I have such script

```
setTimeout(function() 
{
    console.log("Timeout");
}, 1000 * 60);
```

When I run it and change system time back for one hour, the timeout not fires. If I change time forward for one hour, timeout works correctly.

Time is changed by external program which makes call like `ioctl( rtcFd, RTC_SET_TIME, &newTime);`

How to fix this problem?

We use Node.js v0.10.15 on OpenWRT Attitude Adjustment

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just founded that this is a [bug fixed in newer version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33440099/2367294). It fixed by this [commit](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/commit/f8193ab3c46475486eab38543650e2388bd3aedc) in v0.10.33.

If you meet this problem, you need to update or patch your node.js

Comment: To be honest I recommend switching to Node v4 - it's LTS version with superior performance and security.

Comment: Node v5.11 was just released yesterday. https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v5.11.0/

Comment: In our particular case it was difficult to update to latest version v5.11. We solved problem by updating to v0.10.44

Comment: @JohnDifool v4 branch is LTS version, recommended for production - it receives only security patches. v5 branch is stable - it can be used on production, but things are changing and some minor breaking changes can happen.

Answer (score 0):

Use node scheduler this is for time-based scheduling

npm install node-schedule

```
var jobId="123456abc";
schedule.scheduleJob(jobId, new Date(1), function() 
{                                                                                                              
    schedule.cancelJob(jobId);
    // your code here.
});
```